# VBA Excel border around the picture

Tags: excel, vba

Good morning,

Precision my question from yesterday:
[VBA Excel border around the specified picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60100501/vba-excel-border-around-the-specified-picture)

I would like to make automatic borders for most of the images in my Excel document.
I started to record the macro, which looks like this:

```
  Sub Picbodred()
  '
  ' Picbodred Macro
  '

  '
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 2")).Select
     With Selection.ShapeRange.Line
       .Visible = msoTrue
       .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
       .Transparency = 0
   End With
 End Sub
```

But it covers 1 image only, and as it worst this image has assigned ID, which won't be the same.
On top of that I would like to keep some images without borders, as per the pattern below:

[image]

How can I do it?

Comment: Loop through all pictures  `for i = 1 to thisworkbook.sheets("sheetname").Shapes.count` and then set some condition for which pictures you dont want borders? I mean, figuring out which images to not assign borders to is a very specific thing so I guess you will have to be creative here. I can see options like specific names for pics. i.e. `if thisworkbook.sheets("sheetname").Shapes(i).name like "*border" then` or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, lemme just write this as an answer, hihi.

How about you name all pictures you want borders for like so: SomeName_Border and then run this macro:

```
Sub test()

For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheetname").Shapes.Count

    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheetname").Shapes(i).Name Like "*Border" Then

        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheetname").Shapes(i).Line
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            .Transparency = 0
        End With
    End If

Next

End Sub
```

just change the .somethingsomething from the macro recorder to anything recorded with it. If you maybe want thicker lines or something later I mean.

Comment: Is it possible to put the _Border suffix for all pictures at once?

Comment: On phone but: You mean rename all of them? Sure, just loop through them all and add a line like: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheetname").Shapes(i).Name = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheetname").Shapes(i).Name & "_Border"`

Comment: How can I do it within some specified range, as shown in the image above?
I would like to have the image bordered within the big rectangle on the left.
I tried to put sth like this:
For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Civils 1").Range("B2:L46").Shapes.Count, and now I am getting:
Object doesn't support this method

Comment: Seems unnecessarily complicated to do it this way, just rename those manually. If, for some reason, you need to do something to shapes in a range: i just googled: "excel vba select shapes in a range" the first result has what you want. Sorry but going from your `.range.shapes.count` code snippet, it seems you need more info than i can give in a simple comment.