# VBA Excel automatic image resize & border

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to have my image properly resized and bordered with the black line, thickness 1.

My situation looks like this:

[image]

and when I used this code:

```
 Sub ResizeCivilsA()
 SizeToRange Sheets("Civils 1").Pictures("Picture 29"), Range("B3:L46")
 End Sub

 Function SizeToRange(s, Target As Range)
 s.Left = Target.Left + 10
 s.Top = Target.Top - 5
 s.Width = Target.Width
 s.Height = Target.Height
 End Function
```

, everything was adjusted fine, but:

1. It have been done only for the specified shape id, which is "Picture 29"
2. It was without the borders

So I tried then:

```
Sub ResizeCivilsA()
     Dim shp As Shape
     For Each shp In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If shp.Name Like "*Picture*" Then
        SizeToRange shp, Range("B3:L46")
     End If
    Next
```

and finally I am getting error:
**Type mismatch**, with debugger pointing the line:

```
For Each shp In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
```

Regarding the border around the image I found the common solution here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.BorderAround

However after appliance into my work:

```
    Worksheets("Civils 1").Shape("Picture 29").BorderAround _ 
    ColorIndex:=3, Weight:=xlThick
```

it wasn't enough since I had to remove the `_` and got nothing afterward.

Is there some way to have the possibility for instant resizing the image and making the border around it for ANY attached image, which as default is called "Picture..."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

Read code's comments and adjust it to fit your needs

EDIT: The code checks if picture is within target range ad then adjusts its properties.

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ResizeAllShapesInSheet()

    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim targetRange As Range
    Dim targetShape As Shape

    ' Define the sheet that has the pictures
    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Civils 1")
    ' Define the range the images is going to fit
    Set targetRange = targetSheet.Range("B3:L46")

    ' Loop through each Shape in Sheet
    For Each targetShape In targetSheet.Shapes

        ' Check "picture" word in name
        If targetShape.Name Like "*Picture*" Then
            ' Call the resize function
            SizeToRange targetShape, targetRange
        End If

    Next targetShape

End Sub

Private Sub SizeToRange(ByVal targetShape As Shape, ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not (targetShape.Left >= Target.Left And _
        targetShape.Top >= Target.Top And _
        targetShape.Left + targetShape.Width <= Target.Left + Target.Width And _
        targetShape.Top + targetShape.Height <= Target.Top + Target.Height) Then Exit Sub

        ' Adjust picture properties
        With targetShape
            ' Check if next line is required...
            .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
            .Left = Target.Left + 10
            .Top = Target.Top - 5
            .Width = Target.Width
            .Height = Target.Height
        End With

        ' Adjust picture border properties
        With targetShape.Line
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
            .ForeColor.Brightness = 0
            .Transparency = 0
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .Weight = 6
        End With

End Sub
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorText1 - object doesn't support this action

Comment: I have updated the code to check for picture word and also changed the theme color to RGB. Let me know if it works

Comment: Hi, the same problem as in the answer below:
Regarding my previous query:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60111267/vba-excel-border-around-the-picture

I want to have all piuctures adjusted, but only within the B3:L46 range, if it's possible. Unless I must change another shapes ID manually.

Comment: Great. Could you tell me how can I send my image to back?

Comment: Use this property `.ZOrder msoSendToBack`

Comment: Remember to mark the answer if it solves your problem

Comment: Hi,

Unfortunately there is no reaction of your code. Could you write the older version for me please? Thank you in advance.

Comment: OK. I got it. Thanks a lot for the code.
If I remove the IF NOT statement from function, then it starts to be viable.

Answer (score 1):

Initial read looks like your `For Each` is looking for `Shape` objects, but you are giving it a collection of `Sheet` objects.

```
 For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
     For Each shp In sht.Shapes
         If shp.Name Like "*Picture*" Then
             Set r1 = shp.TopLeftCell
             Set r2 = r1.Offset(10, 43)
             SizeToRange shp, Range(r1.Address & ":" & r2.Address)
         End If
     Next shp
 Next sht
```

Hope that helps!

EDIT: Updated with relative address.

Comment: Basically your code works, however everything is resized roughly to the range (B3::46"). What I exactly need is resizing all pictures that have been imported or pasted exactly into this range, not across the whole sheet, as per my previous query below:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60111267/vba-excel-border-around-the-picture

Comment: Let me know if that updated code works for you, @MariuszKrukar, it includes the relative ranges. If you are resizing all shapes on the page, this will likely not work since you may need to move each subsequent shape based on those above and this just changes the size given current location.

Comment: In both codes there is no reaction. Maybe could you bring back the older version? I will eventually change the name of other shapes, what will be easier for me?

Thank you in advance