# VBA Excel automatic resize & border forr multiple shapes on the sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Following my previous query:

[VBA Excel automatic image resize & border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60437604/vba-excel-automatic-image-resize-border)

now I am trying to apply this function for more than 1 image on my sheet:

My code looks like this:

```
 Public Sub ResizeCab()

   Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
   Dim targetRange1 As Range, targetRange2 As Range
   Dim targetShape As Shape

   Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

   Set targetRange1 = targetSheet.Range("B3:L24")
   Set targetRange2 = targetSheet.Range("B25:L46")


   For Each targetShape In targetSheet.Shapes

    If targetShape.Name Like "*Picture*" Then
        SizeToRange targetShape, targetRange1, targetRange2
    End If

   Next targetShape

  End Sub

  Private Sub SizeToRange(ByVal targetShape As Shape, ByVal Target As Range)


         With targetShape

          .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
          .Left = Target.Left + 10
          .Top = Target.Top - 5
          .Width = Target.Width
          .Height = Target.Height
          .ZOrder msoSendToBack
         End With

        With targetShape.Line
           .Visible = msoTrue
           .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
           .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
           .ForeColor.Brightness = 0
           .Transparency = 0
           .Visible = msoTrue
           .Weight = 1
        End With

        End Sub
```

At the line  `SizeToRange targetShape, targetRange1, targetRange2` I am getting an error:

**Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment**

[image]

I would like to have my 2 (or more) imported images resized with the border. Is that possible?

Comment: Your function needs two parameters and you try calling it with three... What `targetRange2` wants to be? Can you poste the code part defining it? What do you want to accomplish using the second range (the third parameter)?

Comment: If you need the third parameter, you can adapt the function to accept it and use where you need. If this is your plan and you  better explain what needed to accomplish, I can help on the issue... If an error appears, it is good to also say what the specific error message is. I think it may be relevant enough to understand where the problem is. If you need both your range, you can make a `Union` of it and call the existing function using the resulted range.

Comment: The second parameter is for the another picture which I would like to adjust in the other part of my sheet. How to adapt my function to this parameter?

Comment: In order to do that, you need to also send that 'another picture' to the function... Without knowing what you intend to do, it is impossible to help you, even if I expressed my disponibility. Why do not separately treat that 'other part of your sheet' and send to the same function the picture itself and the corresponding range? Why such an approach would not look feasible enough? But if you need/want to process the both objects (picture and correspondent range) at once, it is possible. I cannot imagine how you also identify the second picture in order to send it to the function. Do you know?